# How do I update a status label during a very long server operation?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a server operation that typically takes about 15 minutes to complete. I'd like to communicate the various stages of the operation to the user during the operation.

Here is my form code:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="300" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>

<asp:FileUpload ID="upl_UserList" runat="server" />

<p>

    <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update Users" 
        onclick="btn_Update_Click" />

</p>
</form>
```

...and my tick event handler:

```
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_Status.Text = labelText;
        lbl_Status.ForeColor = labelColor;
    }
```

During the time the user clicks the update button, the browser is stuck waiting for the server to respond. This causes the label not to update.

How should I fix this, should I use iframes?

Comment: Try to move the processing to a separate service, a 15 minute process running in a web request is a bad idea.

Comment: I think eventually this will be an automated function that won't require user input. For now we are using a control for debugging the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
    <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
   </Triggers>
```

You place code after update panel and move your timer :

```
  <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="300" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
  </asp:Timer>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl_Status" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```